# How to filter data in Hashmap

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have string called filter my class, which is prepopulated.

String filter="Abcd";

Now I have following code which is reading data from external XML.

```
NodeList quizList = doc.getElementsByTagName("QuizData");

        HashMap<String, String> map = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < quizList.getLength(); i++) {

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            Node firstQuestionNode = quizList.item(i);

            if (firstQuestionNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element firstAircraftElement = (Element) firstQuestionNode;
                // 1.-------
                NodeList idList = firstAircraftElement
                        .getElementsByTagName(KEY_ID);
                Element firstIdElement = (Element) idList.item(0);
                NodeList textIdList = firstIdElement.getChildNodes();
                // --id
                map.put(KEY_ID, textIdList.item(0).getNodeValue().trim());

                // 2.-------
                NodeList typeList = firstAircraftElement
                        .getElementsByTagName(KEY_TYPE);
                Element firstTypeElement = (Element) typeList.item(0);
                NodeList textTypeList = firstTypeElement.getChildNodes();
                // --type
                map.put(KEY_TYPE, textTypeList.item(0).getNodeValue()
                        .trim());

                // 3.-------
                NodeList quesList = firstAircraftElement
                        .getElementsByTagName(KEY_QUES);
                Element firstQuesElement = (Element) quesList.item(0);
                NodeList textQuesList = firstQuesElement.getChildNodes();
                // -- Question
                map.put(KEY_QUES, textQuesList.item(0).getNodeValue()
                        .trim());

                // Add to the Arraylist
                quizDataCollection.add(map);
            }
        }
```

Now I want to filter only those nodes which are having KEY_TYPE= filter. i.e. All the elements where type = Abcd. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: Right now, after you do map.put(KEY_TYPE, whatever), you're overwriting the last thing from KEY_TYPE. You might want to extend the datastructure a little bit, to append to some sort of list